# Find or get the second lower value based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have searched multiple times to find the correct formula for my problem. However, I cannot get it really accurate or precise as needed.  Let me show you a sample of my data

```
ColA   ColB
-----------
BCD2   2009
ABC1   2012
BCD2   2013
ABC1   2011
XYZ3   2013
ABC1   2014
XYZ3   2014
```

From this set of data, ColC should return values (the next lower year) for each row.  The criteria are:

- value should be the next lower value than the value from ColB. (ex. 2014, if 2013 is present then it should return 2013, otherwise the next lower year.)
- the lower values should only be captured from identical lines, identity is set based on values from ColA
- As much as possible, the formula should NOT be an array formula, for better performance as I am working with a lot of data
- if there is no lower value, it should return a blank.

Then based on the above criteria, I must get the following Results:

```
ColA   ColB   ColC
-----------   ----
BCD2   2009   
ABC1   2012   2011
BCD2   2013   2009
ABC1   2011   
XYZ3   2013   
ABC1   2014   2012
XYZ3   2014   2013
```

What I've tried so far:

```
{=LARGE(IF(A2:A11=A2,B2:B11,""),COUNTIF(B2:B11,MAX(B2:B11))+1)}
```

I've tried doing an array formula `=LARGE(array,k)` which contributes to the slow performance of my excel file.  If possible, I'm really hoping to get a formula (not array), to get the desired result.

Hope someone could help me with a straight answer or at least lead me to the right way.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to provide pseudo-LARGEIF() functionality with *k* as *2*. If you generated an array of values with `INDEX` that zeroed anything that did not match column A or was *equal-to-or-greater-than* to column B then the value you are looking for would be the `MAX` of that array. If you want to show empty strings in the cells where no valid return is available, you will have to test for zero with an `IF` statement.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,$A2,$B$2:$B$8,"<"&B2),MAX(INDEX((B$2:B$8)*($A$2:$A$8=$A2)*(B$2:B$8<$B2),,)),"")
```

[image: LARGEIF functionality]

Comment: hi this seems to work beautifully.. if ever i could get a hand on a faster formula, that would be much appreciated. but this is good and ill accept this as the answer.. thanks!

Comment: @E-r Gabriel Doronila - Unfortunately, unsorted data necessitates examining the entire region not once but twice. I've made a change to the primary `IF` condition that reduces that to once with the `IF` determined in a more efficient manner which should improve things somewhat. Thanks for the positive feedback.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using excel 2010 or later you could try using **AGGREGATE** function like this in C2 copied down

`=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,B$2:B$11/(A$2:A$11=A2)/(B$2:B$11< B2),1),"")`

AGGREGATE function can use multiple calculations. 14 is equivalent to **LARGE** so it gives the largest value which meets the criteria, while ignoring errors (6). If there is no such value then an error is returned (#NUM!) so **IFERROR** function can be used to convert that to a blank. "Array entry" is not required

Comment: hi.. this seems to be a better formula and that it could perform better since im using 2010.. but unfortunately, i cannot get it to work.. im using ur formula but is not showing the supposed result

Comment: ok i got it to work.. but i still have to test which can be faster.. thank you barry

Comment: @E-r Gabriel Doronila - OK, excellent - I'm unsure how it will compare with other approaches re speed. Note that not requiring CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER won't necessarily make the formula faster, arrays still have to be processed so a technique like this which avoids array entry may even be **slower** - is your main aim speed?

Comment: ....for example it may be that an array formula like this is quicker than the above `=IFERROR(LARGE(IF(A$2:A$11=A2,IF(B$2:B$11< B2,B$2:B$11)),1),"")`

Comment: yes.. im trying to apply this formula within a macro.. from time to time, there is a function that applies this formula and changes them to value.. doing this via user defined function seem to be really slow.. and doing it combo with the formula can be really fast.. well, i think i can still compare formulas via large chunk of data.. hehe.. i have just started using 2010 last week so.. ill let you know

Comment: are you saying that aggregate is slower because it references "function number".. although it is the same with LARGE function? ill consider doing array formulas in my macro still.. but at first glance, non-array seems to work faster

Comment: No, not AGGREGATE itself but the calculations required for something like `B$2:B$11/(A$2:A$11=A2)/(B$2:B$11< B2)` (i.e. division) might be slower than using multiple IFs as per my comment above - I can't test right now......

Comment: I did some speed tests - I found that the AGGREGATE function performed slightly better than either the array formula with LARGE, or Jeeped's final version - although I should stress that the differences are almost insignificant - 1000 formulas 10x took 3.1 secs to  3.3 for the other two

Comment: hi.. i like yours better.. id like to mark this as the answer but it would be inappropriate since the one i marked previously also solved the original problem.. is there any other way i can add more points to this answer (aside from the check mark)? thanks very much for helping

Answer (score 1):

If you can sort by ColA ascending and ColB descending you could use row offsets. So make your data:

```
ColA    ColB
ABC1    2014
ABC1    2012
ABC1    2011
BCD2    2013
BCD2    2009
XYZ3    2014
XYZ3    2013
```

Then you could do a simple if statement, such as (in `C2`, then dragged down):

```
=IF(A2=A3,B3,"")
```

That will return:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC
ABC1    2014    2012
ABC1    2012    2011
ABC1    2011    
BCD2    2013    2009
BCD2    2009    
XYZ3    2014    2013
XYZ3    2013
```

If you have ColA ascending and ColB ascending, just tweak it to `=IF(A2=A1,B1,"")` i.e.: referencing 1 row above, not below.

Otherwise, I suspect you're probably stuck with an array formula because you're implicitly returning an array at the 'return all of the ColB values with a ColA value matching the current ColA value' stage, before you do the 'then find the next lowest ColB value'.